# How to write a file in android shared internal/external storage?

Tags: android, android-11, android-fileprovider, android-storage

I am currently working with one of my app updates and I am looking for a way to save some files at the root of shared internal storage.
Don't confuse with the word **shared** here. I just meant here with the phone's internal/external storage which holds a large amount of data.

Now coming to the main point, I have an app that uses the [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) library for android and it records the live streams and saves it into the phone's storage.
Now here's the problem I don't want to save this file in my app package folder.
**e.g:** `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.package/files/...`

I want to save this video file in the root of the storage folder where I can create a special folder for my app just like WhatsApp then save all required data in it only.
**e.g:** `/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/...`

***To be more concise I want my app just like WhatsApp which has a separate folder in internal storage for storing its app-related data.***

Now, so far I tried these.

```
getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.package/files
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)?.absolutePath -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.package/files/Download
externalCacheDir?.absolutePath -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.package/cache
filesDir?.absolutePath -> /data/user/0/com.app.package/files
Environment.getRootDirectory().absolutePath -> /system
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath -> /storage/emulated/0
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("").absolutePath -> /storage/emulated/0
```

Now these to methods can work for me but they are deprecated `getExternalStorageDirectory()` & `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`

Just keep in mind my solution is related to the WhatsApp storage folder.
I searched a lot but not so much help as I don't want to go with just a copy-paste and hack solutions. I want to do it in a clean way.

---

I am trying to open a File Picker via intent for this I have set permission
....

....
and for intent.

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.type = "*/*"
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION or
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select .... file"), RC)
```

Now here on Android 10, a file picker is not opening and this works perfectly if I add the `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag in the manifest.
Or
if I set `android:maxSdkVersion="29"` also worked but here google wants to use Some SAF or Media Store API but I don't get it I just want to pick a file just a simple txt nothing else.

Comment: "I want my app just like WhatsApp which has a separate folder in internal storage for storing its app-related data" -- sorry, but that's not really an option anymore on Android 11+. "Now these to methods can work for me but they are deprecated" -- FWIW, [they are undeprecated in Android 12L](https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/11/06/about-environment-undeprecations.html) and are safe for use. However, they do not solve your problem, as you should not be able to create a directory off of the external storage root that way on Android 11+.

Comment: `the WhatsApp storage folder.` ? Where? You are not even telling full path.

Comment: @CommonsWare I haven't used WhatsApp on android 11 but I can still say it's able to save its data outside of its android package directory. Means in a separate WhatsApp folder root of internal storage.
Although there's no problem with saving data inside the android package directory BUT if the app got uninstalled then that data that the folder which OS assigned to my app will also get deleted.
That's why I am looking for a solution like WhatsApp storage.

Comment: @blackapps I have mentioned it already in the root of internal/external storage..
if you have seen WhatsApp and used it then you might also know it create a separate folder in the root of internal storage named WhatsApp.

Comment: By the way @CommonsWare I know I can achieve this with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`  permission but that is a very high-level permission and it's supposed to be for file manager type apps not just for a simple app and I am afraid to use it as later google might not allow me for this app to be on play store.

Comment: `in the root of internal/external storage` That can be anywhere. You should tell full path to begin with. Be serious. And the path is different on different Android versions so telling one full path is not enough. `my solution is related to the WhatsApp storage folder.` And not telling full paths?

Comment: Further i wonder why you keep talking about whatsapp. 
What is so special on it?  There are more apps. Cant you tell your wish in more general terms? So as why not in your apps private folder?

Comment: @blackapps my question is so clear here root means root path what else it can be..it doesn't matter what it's like on other devices...but still, if you are asking look above in my code sample with some outputs which tell the root folder path as well.

Comment: "I haven't used WhatsApp on android 11 but I can still say it's able to save its data outside of its android package directory" -- you are welcome to believe whatever you like. For devices where WhatsApp is pre-installed, I agree that it is possible that WhatsApp could store things in a directory off of the external storage root. In those situations, device manufacturers can give WhatsApp rights that apps that you and I write cannot have. And, Facebook has a history of exploiting security bugs for its own benefit, and I cannot rule out that scenario.

Comment: hmm well, thanks, @CommonsWare got more closed to my solution during research and better understanding..below i am posting another problem..take a look at that as well if you have any idea about this.

Comment: @blackapps The path is `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp`, whereas normal app uses `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{packageName}`. WhatsApp seems to violate the scoped storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can save video file to external storage using this:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
@Throws(FileNotFoundException::class)
fun addToApiAbove29Gallery(
    context: Context,
    file: File?,
    fileName: String?,
    destinationPath: String?,
    action: () -> Unit
) {
    val valuesvideos: ContentValues
    valuesvideos = ContentValues()
    valuesvideos.put(
        MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                + File.separator + context.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
                + File.separator + File(destinationPath).name
    )
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "${fileName}.mp4")
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "${fileName}.mp4")
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
    val resolver = context.contentResolver
    val collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    val uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos)
    val pfd = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo!!, "w")
    val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    executor.execute {
        if (pfd != null) {
            try {
                val out =
                    FileOutputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor)
                val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
                val buf = ByteArray(8192)
                var len: Int
                while (inputStream.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len)
                }
                out.close()
                inputStream.close()
                pfd.close()
                valuesvideos.clear()
                valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
                try {
                    setExifFromUri(
                        context,
                        uriSavedVideo,
                        File(destinationPath)
                    )
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            handler.post {
                context.contentResolver.update(uriSavedVideo, valuesvideos, null, null)
                action()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note that this code is only for android 10 and above, because you can easily save the video file to ecternal storage below android 10.**